# Why did the server receive the first message but not the second message ("how are you")? (multithreaded java socket programming)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to create a text messaging program with three files (main function file, client file, server file)

If "-l" is present on the command line, it will run as a server, otherwise it will run as a client

Command line arguments to run server:

```
java DirectMessengerCombined -l 3000
```

Command line arguments to run client:

```
java DirectMessengerCombined 3000
```

All three files need to be able  to access String args[] in the main function file because that is how it gets the port number

Screenshot of error (Server on left, client on right):

[image: screenshot of error]

The problem with this screenshot is that the "how are you" message is never received by the server (left window)

Code of Server file (DirectMessengerServer):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.IIOException;


public class DirectMessengerServer
{

    private String[] serverArgs; // <-- added variable
    private static Socket socket;
    public boolean keepRunning = true;
    int ConnectOnce = 0;

    public DirectMessengerServer(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        // set the instance variable
        this.serverArgs = args;
        run();
    }

      public String[] ServerRun(String[] args) throws IOException 
      {
          //How do I get the String[] args in this method be able to access it in the run methods?
        serverArgs = args;
        serverArgs = Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length);

        return serverArgs;

      }




Thread ListeningLoop = new Thread();    
//run method of ServerRecieve
public void run() throws IOException
{  


    try
    {
        if(ConnectOnce == 0)
        {
            int port_number1 = Integer.valueOf(serverArgs[1]);
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
            socket = serverSocket.accept(); 
            ConnectOnce = 4;
        }
        while(keepRunning)
        {

            //Reading the message from the client

//BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String MessageFromClient = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from client: "+ MessageFromClient);

           // ServerSend.start();

            runSend();



        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}

Thread ServerSend = new Thread ();

//Run method of ServerSend
public void runSend()
{   
    while(keepRunning)
    {
        System.out.println("Server sending thread is now running");
        try
        {         

            //Send the message to the server
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

            //creating message to send from standard input
            String newmessage = "";
            try 
            {
                // input the message from standard input
                BufferedReader input= new BufferedReader( 
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String line = "";

                line= input.readLine(); 
                    newmessage += line + " ";

            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
            }
            String sendMessage = newmessage;
            bw.write(sendMessage + "\n");
            bw.flush();
            System.out.println("Message sent to client: "+sendMessage);
            run();
        }


        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
}


}
```

Code of client (DirectMessengerClient):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class DirectMessengerClient
{
    private String[] clientArgs; // <-- added variable
    private static Socket socket;
    public boolean keepRunning = true;
    public DirectMessengerClient(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        // set the instance variable
        this.clientArgs = args;
        run(args);


    }
    public String[] ClientRun(String[] args)
    {
        clientArgs = args;
        clientArgs = Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length);
        return clientArgs;
    }

    Thread ClientSend = new Thread();   
    public void run(String args[]) throws IOException
    {   
        System.out.println("Client send thread is now running");
        while(keepRunning)
        {             
             String port_number1= args[0];
             System.out.println("Port number is: " + port_number1);
             int port = Integer.valueOf(port_number1);
             String host = "localhost";
             InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
             socket = new Socket(address, port);


             //Send the message to the server
             OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
             OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
             BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

             //creating message to send from standard input
             String newmessage = "";
             try 
             {
                 // input the message from standard input
                 BufferedReader input= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                 String line = "";

                 line= input.readLine(); 
                 newmessage += line + " ";


              }
              catch ( Exception e )
              {
                     System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
              }
                String sendMessage = newmessage;
                bw.write(sendMessage + "\n");
                bw.flush();
                System.out.println("Message sent to server: "+sendMessage);
                runClientRead(args);
            }

        }


    Thread ClientRead = new Thread();
    public void runClientRead(String args[]) throws IOException
    {   
        System.out.println("Client recieve/read thread is now running");

            //Integer port= Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
            //String host = "localhost";
            //InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            //socket = new Socket(address, port);

            //Get the return message from the server
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String MessageFromServer = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from server: " + MessageFromServer);

    }
}
```

Code of main function file (DirectMessengerCombined):

```
 import java.io.IOException;

public class DirectMessengerCombined
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        DirectMessengerClient client1 = null;
        DirectMessengerServer server1 = null;

          for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
          {

              if (args.length == 1) 
              {
                 client1  = new DirectMessengerClient(args);
                 client1.ClientRun(args);
              }
              else if (args.length == 2)
              {
                 server1 = new DirectMessengerServer(args);
                 server1.ServerRun(args);
              }
           i=args.length + 20;
          } 
    }

}
```

My question is: Why is the server able to accept the first message but not able to accept the second message ("how are you")?

Comment: Um, you never assing a `Runable` to `ListeningLoop` or `ServerSend`.  Nor do you start `ListeningLoop`.

Comment: @bradimus how do I add a runnable to the ListeningLoop or ServerSend functions?

Comment: Looks like your runSend() method in the server calls run() again inside its loop, how are you planning on that to play out  ? The server will just receive a message and then call run() where it waits for  another connection.

Comment: Start in the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Comment: @nos the run method has a ConnectOnce variable that is designed to wait for a connection only one time because after it gets accepted it is assigned the 4 variable. look at `if(ConnectOnce == 0 )`

Comment: Well then you are wrapping the socket again with a BufferedReader, what if the previous BufferReader you attached to the socket still has data in it ? I suggest you remove the call to run() from runSend(), the runSend() method already contains a loop, and you will have a very hard time to follow your code when it performs all the recursive calls you have added to it when you call run() inside this loop...

Comment: @nos I am not sure how to handle data from the previous bufferedReader but the reason I need to call the run() which is located at the end of the runSend() method is because I use the run() method to receive messages from the client (if I don't use the Run() method then it will only be able to recieve one message instead of infinite) I would eventually like to send and recieve messages simultaneously using threads somehow